# How to change logo and add a colored border to the bottom of my fixed header when user scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a lot of information online regarding header effects on scroll and I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out on my own. I was hoping to find a way to do this without using JS but there doesn't seem to be a way. I've tried just adding a simple effect (changing height of header on scroll) using JS ... hoping that once I got the header to actually respond to this I could work with it to make the effects that I'm wanting.  But I can't even get the header to respond. Ultimately I'm wanting the header to slightly reduce in height, the logo will change to a different image and there will be a 15px colored border added to the bottom. I know that's a lot for a novice web designer to try to attempt but I'd really love to figure out how to do it. Any help or direction to good online resources for this would be so appreciated.

I'm adding only my html and css just to keep things less cluttered.  I can add what I've tried in my js file if I need to. I've commenting out some css that went with the js that clearly doesn't work.  Thanks in advance for your time.

```
 <header>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="nav_left">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </div>
            <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="Claire Crawford"
                    id="logo_Claire" /></a>
            <div id="nav_right">
                <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```
header {
  height: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  /* border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(197, 179, 55) */
}

/* header border on scroll
header.fixed.scrolled .header_bottom .container_inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
} */

/* header.sticky {
  height: 120px;
} */

/* header {
  transition: padding 300ms ease;
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in your actual code. It might work well

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('#logo img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!');
      $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "none");
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
      $('#logo img').attr('src', 'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*4mdh6im57oFHSNY4syD_2Q.png');
      $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "2px solid red");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  /* border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(197, 179, 55) */
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_left">
        <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
      </div>
      <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="noHover"><img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*4mdh6im57oFHSNY4syD_2Q.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
      <div id="nav_right">
        <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

I am telling you step by step: 
1. add this to your index.html page. you need to add jquery to work this code. `<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
2. Then copy paste my code into your js file and edit it as you want.
3. i have write a funtion to scroll. you can see i have write 200 so that if you scroll 200px below the logo will change. so there are two condition I have written

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('#logo img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!');
      $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "none");
    }
```

this one is for after you scroll 200px and the other one is your initial stage.

3. `$('#logo img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/220?text=Original+Logo!');`
   here #logo is the id from html and img is for img inside logo div.

4.`$("#nav").css("border-bottom", "none");`  nav is for nav div and I added border css by adding .css here

Comment: thank you. Forgive me as I know very little about JS.  So I need to edit your code and add my original logo img and the one I want to be displayed upon scroll ... Example: .. "$('#logo img').attr('src', images/claire_logo.png');"   and then ... $('#logo img').attr('src', 'images/claire_new_logo.png');  but what else would I need to replace to make this work?

Comment: if you need to add border add  $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "2px solid red"); this line and change the color as you want. moreover please accept the answer as accepted answer :)

Comment: one more thing if you are not using jqury to your project please <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> add this to your index.html file and copy paste my code below your html code

Comment: Can you read my first comment above.  I'm not sure how I need to edit your code to make it work.  And do you mean that I don't need to add your code to a separate JS file and that I can simple include it in my html file ?

Comment: either include it in your js file or include it underneath your html code by using <script>code here </script> tag. i guess you are clear now

Comment: No, I'm not clear.  You haven't responded to the first comment. I don't know how to use the code you offered.  There needs to be some editing to customize it for my needs but I don't understand how to edit it to even know if it will work.

Comment: check out the answer now. I have update it with explanation and what you to do to make this work or change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195777/discussion-between-irin-and-vienne).